# How to using Evernote to open Evernote note link in Emacs org mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, evernote

I want to open Evernote note link in Emacs/Emacs org mode. The Evernote note link is like following:

```
evernote:///view/52572/s1/8eb24719-30d3-4fd8-8e4c-f826da7bf2a5/8eb24719-30d3-4fd8-8e4c-f826da7bf2a5/
```

If I put this link in Firefox, it will use Evernote to run the link and jump to the exact place in Evernote.

But in Emacs it does not open as in Firefox. I want Emacs to open the above link as Firefox do. How can I do it? Or how can I open it as Google Chrome do?

Comment: http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html#Adding-hyperlink-types

Comment: What happens when you open the link in Emacs?

Comment: What does happen when you try to open a link of that sort in emacs?  Does it do anything or simply state that it doesn't know how to open links of that type?

Comment: nothing, Emacs just reminds me that "no match".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following causes links in org-mode documents with unrecognized protocols to be handed off to `browse-url` which should cause them to get dispatched to the appropriate handlers (at least in Os X)

```
(defun org-pass-link-to-system (link)
  (if (string-match "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+:" link)
     (browse-url link)
    nil)
  )

(add-hook 'org-open-link-functions 'org-pass-link-to-system)
```

Comment: I use this code, and it works under Emacs 24.2 and Windows7. Now I can open Evernote link directly in Emacs Org Mode by just click the Evernote Note links.